# Lost Connection to MySQL Server

Tags: mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql

I'm connecting to a ~30GB database on Google Cloud SQL using MySQL Workbench. However, when I try to query the data, I get the error:

- Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

This error always occurs at 900 seconds, so it's only a concern for slower queries.

I have increased DBMS connection read time out, but am not sure what else could be causing this.

Comment: Can you indicate more precisely how you set the timeouts? Are you using the [MySQL Flags](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-flags) feature?

Comment: Sounds like it's a google cloud issue. For example, see https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#sometimes_slow as 15 minutes == 900 seconds. Perhaps this is the cause? That also refers to how the alter this behavior.

Comment: Philip: I followed the instructions and set the instance to always active, but that didn't help

Comment: Razvan, I have set the MySQL flags: 
innodb_lock_wait_timeout
max_allowed_packet
wait_timeout
interactive_timeout

to their maximums, is there another flag I should be looking at adding?

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud SQL could accept several "timeout" parameters.

Check actual parameter with this select :

mysql>  show global variables like '%timeout%';

and try to raise it from DevConsole, modifying the CloudSQL tier